# oauth twitter not working in android devices

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, cordova-plugins

I created a twitter client app in cordova using oauth protocol. In windows phone, app is fetching the request token and retrieving the tweets. But in android device,fetch request token is not working. Receiving the error `{"text":"", "xml":"", requestHeaders": {}, "responseHeaders": {shouldInterceptRequest}}`. I am using the same code for both platforms.

I used the following code for fetching token:

```
var oauth = OAuth({
consumerKey: "XXXX", // REPLACE HERE TO YOUR CONSUMER KEY or API KEY
consumerSecret: "XXXX", //    REPLACE HERE TO YOUR CONSUMER SECRET or API SECRET
accessToken: "XXXX",
accessTokenSecret: "XXXX",
callbackUrl: "http://twitter.com",
requestTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
authorizationUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate",
accessTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
});


function onLoad() {
  oauth.fetchRequestToken(function (url) {
    alert("Opening Request Token URL: " + url);
    Login(url);
}, function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

});
```